# django-helpdesk 0.4.1 "extendMarkdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'md_globals'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, markdown, django-helpdesk

When I try to view /tickets/1/ I get the error:

```
extendMarkdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'md_globals'

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/markdown/core.py, line 115, in registerExtensions
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The causes are:

- that the Markdown library has changed its function arguments between 3.1 and 3.4
- and that Django Helpdesk 0.4.1 only requires "markdown", not a specific, compatible, version.

Downgrading Markdown fixed the issue:

```
fadedbee@box:~$ sudo pip3 list | grep arkdown
Markdown               3.4.1

fadedbee@box:~$ sudo pip3 install "Markdown<3.2"
Collecting Markdown<3.2
  Downloading Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 87 kB 908 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Markdown<3.2) (52.0.0)
Installing collected packages: Markdown
  Attempting uninstall: Markdown
    Found existing installation: Markdown 3.4.3
    Uninstalling Markdown-3.4.3:
      Successfully uninstalled Markdown-3.4.3
Successfully installed Markdown-3.1.1
```

Comment: Update Djanjo version 5